# Eclipse hangs when compiling huge .java file

Tags: java, eclipse, protocol-buffers

In a java project I'm working on, I need to use some very large protobufs. One of the .java files generated by protoc is approximately 8.3 MB. When I add that file to my project in eclipse, it hangs indefinitely.

Is there any way to fix this? Perhaps precompile that file with javac and tell eclipse not to bother building it?

Comment: What is the platform i.e Windows/ Linux ? And 8.3 MB java file !!!

Comment: @pundit Yes, it's quite impressive. I bet he's generating data in arrays and links it statically, rather then loading them at run time.

Comment: Windows 7 Professional, x64. I haven't tried to use ant, but I have tried maven. Maven sort of works, it compiles, but has a whole lot of other issues that makes it unusable. Also, data in arrays, just a whole lot of getters and setters for a very big protocol buffer.

Comment: Does it need to be one big protocol buffer ???, can you split the protocol buffer up and read / send several protocol buffers instead of one ???. Even if you get over the current issues, you may have problems in the future when you add extra fields to the protocol buffer !!!

Comment: I can't split it up or modify it in any way (and it won't change). It's not my protocol buffer, it's a protocol buffer for someone else's API.

Comment: You can compile it once, and put it in jar file. After that just add jar as dependency to your project.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what I'll have to do, as long as I can get ant/maven/javac/whatever to compile it properly.

Comment: Have you tried [increasing the heap size](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F) for Eclipse?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried increasing the min to 2 GiB and the max to 3 GiB, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem when moved from Javac -target 1.7 to 1.8 in Maven, compiling my project takes more than 10 minutes.

```
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

What I found is to be a bug in Oracle Hotspot JDK compiler, since I also have IBM SDK, and project compiles very fast (in less than a minute).

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwi3280sr2-20151023_01(SR2))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 Windows 7 x86-32 20151019_272764 (JIT 
enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R28_Java8_SR2_20151019_2144_B272764
JIT  - tr.r14.java_20151006_102517.04
GC   - R28_Java8_SR2_20151019_2144_B272764
J9CL - 20151019_272764)
JCL - 20151022_01 based on Oracle jdk8u65-b17
```

So hopefully this helps other developers which have issues when compiling source code for target 1.8 which is hanging or taking a lot to complete. Is much better to use a IBM SDK java compiler.

Edit 1.

IBM Sdk is now open sourced and called OpenJ9, it can be obtained for Windows 64-bit in this URL: 
[jdk8u181-b13_openj9-0.9.0](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=openj9#x64_win)

This has no cost and has same performance as IBM SDK 8 for Windows which is no longer available for free to download.

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM (build openj9-0.9.0, JRE 1.8.0 Windows 7 amd64-64-Bit 
Compressed References 20180813_153 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 24e53631
OMR      - fad6bf6e
JCL      - a05586ac based on jdk8u181-b13)
```